# Referencing property in mongoDB by taking _id

Tags: mongodb, objectid

I have a collection which have a document like this:

```
collection 1
{
  _id: ObjectID(),
  name: foo
}
```

I would get ObjectID of the above collection and copy into a document of another collection in order to reference correctly. Should I do simply:

```
db.collection1.find({name:"foo"},{_id:1})
```

EDIT
[image]

Comment: I'm trying to taking the _id by calling the command var x= db.collection1.find({name:"foo"},{_id:1}); x._id but I don't get anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `find` will return a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/). Cursors works like an iterator in other languages. You can either attempt to find the first element in the cursor using the `next()` function and then get it's `_id` property or simplify your statement using `findOne`:

```
var x = db.collection1.findOne({name:"foo"}, {_id:1});
var id = x._id;
```

This is making an assumption that you are getting a document back from that query. You'll probably want to add a `null` check on `x` before grabbing the `_id` property.

Comment: I get the document but when I call x._id the value is empty

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot the value is properly saved but when I call ._id I don't get anything. it is weird

Comment: Does the same happen when you use `findOne` instead of `find`?

Comment: In that case I get the ObjectID value. Great!!! Thank you. But why the result is different?

Comment: I mentioned in the first paragraph. `find` returns a `cursor` which is like a list of documents matching your query. `findOne` effectively does the same, but pulls the first document out of the list automatically for you. Read up on cursors, you'll be using them a lot in Mongo. :)